# How do I update an existing object with multiple values from a global function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the following object in a JS script I'm working on:

```
let time = {
    years: 0,
    months: 0
};
```

I also have a global helper function, on a seperate file, that calculates the total years and months given a number of months:

```
helpers.monthsToYears = function(months) {
    var totalYears = months / 12;
    return [Math.floor(totalYears), Math.round((totalYears - Math.floor(totalYears)) * 12)];
};
```

I want to update my `time` array using the global function, but I am unsure as to how to do this simply.

I've searched and found ways to *create* a new object from a function's output, but not how to update an existing object.

I have tried things like:

```
    time[years,months] = helpers.monthsToYears(results.months);
```

but to no result.

Would anyone know the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```js
// destructuring assignment
const [ years, months ] = helpers.monthsToYears(results.months)
// that's equivalent to
// const res = helpers.monthsToYears(results.months)
// const years = res[0]; const months = res[1]

time = { months, years }
// or
// time.months = months
// time.years = years
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the meaning of "update an existing object" you are referring to, based on Zac Anger's answer above, you can also perform:

```js
time.years += years;
time.months += months;

if (time.months >= 12) {
    time.years += Math.floor(time.months / 12);
    time.months = time.months % 12;
}
```